# What does it mean when git only shows a directory containing untracked files, but not the files themselves?

Tags: git, subdirectory, git-status

Relative newbie to git, so this may be something pretty basic. On the other hand, I searched around quite a bit for this answer before asking.

In my git repository, if I create any files in a particular subdirectory (a few levels down from the main repository directory), and run `git status`, git doesn't list the files in that directory, but just its name.

I would have thought that it had something to do with how many levels down it is, but other untracked files in other subdirectories the same number of levels away (or more) are listed without any problem.

Anyone know if there's some setting or some entry in some file somewhere that would cause this behaviour?

Comment: try `git status -u --ignored`. also check the `.gitignore` file

Comment: Well, now it's stopped doing that - the files in the affected folder are now being listed individually. As far as I can recall, I didn't make any change to either the directory (other than adding/removing files to try to figure out what was going on) or any of the commands I was using. Just some random weirdness, I guess. Thanks for everyone's input!

Comment: What `git --version` are you using? You can check your `.gitconfig` to see if there's anything set there, too.

Comment: Version is 1.9.1. Nothing obvious in .gitconfig - just user info, settings for various tools (merge, diff, etc), and some aliases (none of which I used when I encountered this issue).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not show the files inside untracked directories by default because of performance reasons - it should `ls` the untracked directory, as `git` doesn't have it's content indexed.

From [`git help status`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status/2.2.0):

> `-u[<mode>]`
>
> `--untracked-files[=<mode>]`
>
> Show untracked files.
>
> The `mode` parameter is optional (defaults to `all`), and is used to specify the handling of untracked files.
>
> The possible options are:
>
> `no` - Show no untracked files
>
> `normal` - Shows untracked files and directories
>
> `all` - Also shows individual files in untracked directories.
>
> When `-u` option is not used, untracked files and directories are shown (i.e. the same as specifying `normal`), to help you avoid forgetting to add newly created files. Because it takes extra work to find untracked files in the filesystem, this mode may take some time in a large working tree. You can use `no` to have `git status` return more quickly without showing untracked files.
>
> The default can be changed using the `status.showUntrackedFiles` configuration variable documented in [git-config(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: So for those playing along at home, the exact syntax of the command to change to the expected behavior is `git config --global status.showuntrackedfiles all`